# How to disable CTRL + K + D in Visual studio in certain parts of the code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use CTRL + K + D to format my code all the time and I think it's good. But sometimes I need to format my code in another way e.g. in an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum OrdklasseTyper : long
   {
    [Display(Name = "x")]
    Udefineret = 0L,
    [Display(Name = "A")]
    Adjektiv = 1L << 0,
    [Display(Name = "D")]
    Adverbium = 1L << 1,
    ....
   }
```

Because I have about 60 values in the enum I would prefer to write it:

```
[Flags]
public enum OrdklasseTyper : long
  {
    [Display(Name = "x")]        Udefineret = 0L,
    [Display(Name = "A")]        Adjektiv =   1L << 0,
    [Display(Name = "D")]        Adverbium =  1L << 1,
    ....
  }
```

because i it makes it more readable. CTRL + K + D will change it back to the format shown in the upper example.

Is there an equivalent to **#pragma warning disable/restore** which can disable CTRL + K + D in certain parts of the code on your own choice?

Comment: not a particularly enlightening idea, but: you could always just.... not press ctrk + k, d? if the enum is in a separate file, this should be fine

Comment: @MarcGravell, It's all about how easy it is to read your code. In this specific example it could be a possibility, but sometimes a have the problem/need inside a method etc. That's why I need a general solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight out of msdn, tested in vs 2022 v17.6.3:

```
#pragma warning disable IDE0055
// The code that's violating the rule is on this line.
// Even multiple lines works well.
#pragma warning restore IDE0055
```